# Attachment sent through email is of 0KB size

Tags: android, android-intent, email-client

I am developing an application in which I have to send an image through email. I succeeded in sending email, but the attachment sent is of 0KB size. I am not getting what is the problem. Below, I am posting my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class EtestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button email;
Intent in;
private static final String TAG = "EmailLauncherActivity";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    email = (Button)findViewById(R.id.email);
    email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                in.setType("image/jpeg");
                in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/android.jpg"));

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(in, "Email..."));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "email sending failed", e);
            }//catch
        }//onClick
    });
}//onCreate
}//class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face the same problem which is solved by changing MIME type.

Try this  in.setType("image/jpg");

Comment: One more problem I am facing is as I have used createchooser(), it is showing list of all applications that are capable of sending the file but I want only list of email clients. Can you please tell me how to get that?

Comment: Try with Intent.ACTION_SENDTO instead of Intent.ACTION_SEND

Answer (score 0):

Was your phone mounted to your computer at the time? The SD card may be inaccessible while connected to your computer, so it may not actually be attaching the image.

Comment: No, I had given sd card support to my emulator in which I had kept the image. Same application I tested on my phone separately and also I kept an image in  sd card named as android.jpg. But, I am facing same problem in both cases